# Getting issue in XmlAgg fuction in teradata

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I am getting below issue  when using 'XmlAgg'function in teradata.

Code:-

```
,Trim(Trailing '|' FROM ( XmlAgg(EDW1.sr_part_tracking_desc || '|'   ORDER BY EDW1.req_line_id) (VARCHAR(4000)) ) )
```

Issue:

`*** Failure 7548 13 The target type is not large enough to accomodate the results of the cast.`

Please help, it is very critical for me.

tried

```
substr(Trim(Trailing '|' FROM ( XmlAgg(EDW1.sr_part_tracking_desc || '|'   ORDER BY EDW1.req_line_id) (VARCHAR(4000)) ) ),1,4000)
```

but same issue.

```
Trim(Trailing '|' FROM ( XmlAgg(EDW1.sr_part_tracking_desc || '|'   ORDER BY EDW1.req_line_id) (VARCHAR(4000)) ) )
```

Issue: `*** Failure 7548 13 The target type is not large enough to accomodate the results of the cast.`

Comment: How is `EDW1.sr_part_tracking_desc` defined?

Comment: This column is combination of three columns.

Comment: Code: ,COALESCE(part_id, ' ')||'_'||COALESCE(part_ordrd_nbr, ' ')||'_'||COALESCE(airbill_nbr, ' ').   part_ordrd_nbr and airbill_nbr can be null.